# How to access an object property dynamically?

Tags: stylus

So, Im trying to use a for in loop to generate some classes (using Stylus preprocessor).

I have defined an object like this:

```
$color = {
  ... (lot of properties) ...
  product: {
    product1  : {
      base    : #8c735e,
      dark    : #715544,
      darkest : #674b3c
    },
    product2  : {
      base    : #a77c3e,
      dark    : #8f6129,
      darkest : #835020
    },
    product2  : {
      base    : #6d91a4,
      dark    : #4d748c,
      darkest : #416d88
    },
  }
  ... (lot of properties) ...
}
```

What I want to produce is the following:

```
.product-is--product1 {
  h1, h2 { color: #715544; }  
} 
.product-is--product2 {
  h1, h2 { color: #8f6129; }  
} 
.product-is--product3 {
  h1, h2 { color: #4d748c; }  
}
```

What I have tried is something like this:

```
products = product1, product2, product3;

for product in products {
  .product-is {
    &--{product} {
      h1, h2 { color: $color.product[product].dark; }
    }
  }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work. Tried lot of different combinations and google, stack overflowed it, read the docs, etc, but nothing.

Does anybody know how can I access the $color object based on the value on the for ?

Comment: what language is this  ?

Comment: Stylus, as specified on the question tag. Anyway, I edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate right through the object, getting the key and the values like this:

```
$color = {
  product: {
    product1  : {
      base    : #8c735e,
      dark    : #715544,
      darkest : #674b3c
    },
    product2  : {
      base    : #a77c3e,
      dark    : #8f6129,
      darkest : #835020
    },
    product3  : {
      base    : #6d91a4,
      dark    : #4d748c,
      darkest : #416d88
    },
  }
}

for $product_key, $product_colors in $color.product {
  .product-is {
    &--{$product_key} {
      h1, h2 { color: $product_colors.dark; }
    }
  }
}
```

But I've tried the example you provided in the latest Stylus (0.52.4) and it works:

```
$color = {
  product: {
    product1  : {
      base    : #8c735e,
      dark    : #715544,
      darkest : #674b3c
    },
    product2  : {
      base    : #a77c3e,
      dark    : #8f6129,
      darkest : #835020
    },
    product3  : {
      base    : #6d91a4,
      dark    : #4d748c,
      darkest : #416d88
    },
  }
}

products = product1, product2, product3;

for product in products {
  .product-is {
    &--{product} {
      h1, h2 { color: $color.product[product].dark; }
    }
  }
}
```

As well as my first example both generate

```
.product-is--product1 h1,
.product-is--product1 h2 {
  color: #715544;
}
.product-is--product2 h1,
.product-is--product2 h2 {
  color: #8f6129;
}
.product-is--product3 h1,
.product-is--product3 h2 {
  color: #4d748c;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot, this is working now. Problem was typo on my "real world" code. Thanks a lot, you put me on the right spot :)